# How do I search nodes of XML document for text? Or convert to SQL tables?

Tags: sql, xml, search

I have an XML file and would like to run a search on the nodes for text that matches user input.  My options are:

1. Convert the XML file to a SQL table and run the search against the table records.
2. Search the XML nodes themselves.

The problem is that I cannot find a open source conversion utility, nor can I figure out how to search the XML nodes.

I can use PHP, Ruby, or Python for the search code.

Any pointers on how can I do 1 or 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, define an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) expression that corresponds to the search to perform, then use one of the many XML bindings to to apply it to the XML document.

Comment: If the XML can fit into memory and is well-formed you can use SimpleXml's xpath function here: [http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php]